# How to add header files in Atmel Studio 6

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, avr, atmel, avr-studio5

I'm trying to go with Atmel Atudio 6. But i'm not sure how to add .h files to my project. Is that something allowed? if so, how can i add them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to add an existing .h file, you simply right-click your ***project*** in the *"Solution Explorer"*

If you don't have the Solution Explorer view open, you will find it under the menu item *"View -> Solution Explorer"*).

In the pop-up menu, you then select *"Add -> Existing Item..."* (Ctrl+Alt+A)

Now you can browse to locate your .h file, select it and press *"Add"*.

**Notice** the little drop down arrow on the *"Add"* button. You can use that to select whether you want to copy the .h file to your project, or just add a link to the existing file.

If you want to add a new file, right-click your project, and select *"Add -> New Item..."* (Ctrl+Shift+A) and select the *"Include File"* template.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Sorry for the dumb question. I'm new to this (actually, started today). Can you point me to a **good** tutorial (from basics to advanced stuff). I'll catch up. I've already become successful with USART communication. But unlike in the case of PICs , I couldn't find any proper Atmel tutorial..

Comment: I guess you could search the AVR Freaks forum for links to tutorials: http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=index Perhaps take a look at this one: http://metku.net/index.html?path=articles/microcontroller-part-1/index_eng3 Atmel have also produced some short videos on YouTube with various tips & tricks on how to use Atmel Studio: http://www.youtube.com/user/AtmelCorporation

Comment: Well, avrfreaks is a good forum. But I was looking for something more like a tutorial. And the second link just talk about the basics, which I already understand. But anyway, thanks for the help. Maybe I'll learn in the hard way..
(I'm a bit experienced with PIC programming. I felt like of going for this after I got my Arduino Mega. Feel like the Arduino IDE is too childish)

Answer (score 4):

Often it's better to add an include directory where the compiler looks for include files (specifically those included with < > marks).

This can be done in Atmel Studio 6: Project properties -> Toolchain -> ARM/GNU C Compiler* -> Directories -> Add Item (button with green plus sign).

*will be AVR/GNU C Compiler if using an AVR board.

Comment: I is really helpful. My Atmel Studio 8 refused to work without this config. Thanks.